# Google Maps: add multiple map markers

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My setup currently I have a custom map marker for multiple points on my map, but I want to add different map markers for different markers on the map dependant on their `type` attribute. My current setup as follows: 
HTML

```
<div class="marker" data-lat="LATITUDE_GOES_HERE" data-lng="LONGITUTE_GOES_HERE" type="library">
```

jQuery (just the marker function)

```
function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

    // var
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';

    // create marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position    : latlng,
        map         : map,
        icon: iconBase + 'schools_maps.png'
    });

    // add to array
    map.markers.push( marker );

    // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if( $marker.html() )
    {
        // create info window
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content     : $marker.html()
        });

        // show info window when marker is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            infowindow.open( map, marker );

        });
    }

}
```

This works great, but how would I had a different marker icon for different markers on the map, dependant on the `type` attribute they have (if possible)?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Marker Show/hide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844915/google-maps-marker-show-hide/24846077#24846077).  Includes an [example fiddle with markers based on category](http://jsfiddle.net/YEPB7/6/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Multiple Custom Markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266772/google-maps-multiple-custom-markers)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using custom pin icon in Google maps only shows first location in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863825/using-custom-pin-icon-in-google-maps-only-shows-first-location-in-loop)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949867/how-can-i-modify-the-markers/23951393#23951393 

Readmore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like.....

```
var iconName = "";
var type = $marker.attr("type");
if (type == "library")
    iconName = "library.png";
else if (type == "school")
    iconName = "school.png";
// ...etc...

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position    : latlng,
    map         : map,
    icon: iconBase + iconName;
});
```

Of course, you would have to provide (and probably host) the icons yourself...